# Powershell WinForms UI refresh / live update

Tags: multithreading, winforms, powershell, user-interface

I'm currently pulling my hair out trying to update a Winforms UI using the 'Register-objectevent' Cmdlet.

What I'm trying to do is get the Register-ObjectEvent to update the label in the form ever tick on the timer.

I've done hours of research on this, and I know it's something to do with multithreading / invoking, but I can't get my head around how to make it work !

If someone could show me / help me to get this script to update the label on the form by the timer, that would be amazing ! I've got lots of Winforms that would benifit from multithreading, but I need to get my head around it first !

Here's the script I'm trying to get working, any help is greatly appreciated :)

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles() | out-null
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form


$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{
$form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 600
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 1200
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$form1.MaximizeBox = $False
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$form1.KeyPreview = $True
$form1.FormBorderStyle = 1
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.StartPosition = 1
$form1.backcolor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,240,240,240)



$timer = New-Object System.Timers.Timer
$timer.Interval = 1000 
$timer.AutoReset = $true  
$timeout = 0




$num=0
$action = { 
$num++
    write-host "test"
    $vollabel.text=$num
    $timer.stop()
}  
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -SourceIdentifier TimerElapsed -EventName          Elapsed -Action $action
$timer.start()


$vollabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$vollabel.Location = "0,0"
$form1.Controls.Add($vollabel)




$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
$form1.Add_Shown({$form1.Activate()})
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
```

Comment: Do you really need to use PowerShell for this? Because you're trying to cut down a sequoia with a plastic knife :) PowerShell is not good at creating complex applications, just good at running scripts. In particular it does not handle multi-threading (what you've discovered yourself) and AFAIK at best it only manages background jobs. So if possible use a language like C# and this kind of things will become a breeze and you'll be able to concentrate more on the goal than the plumbing. (and as a bonus you'll get rid of all these horrible '$') :)

Comment: PowerShell is great for simple UI like `$processes = Get-Process | Out-GridView -Title 'Select Processes' -PassThru` and simple custom UI too. Cool idea though. Hope you get it working. Can you create a button that will increment the number by one every time you press it? You might try looking at an HTA.

Comment: Managed to get it working! After HOURS of research, turns out the best way to 'sort of / bodge' multithreading is to put the form controls into a synced hash table. In the powershell script you create a seperate powershell session (the UI) then using the main script you can change the hashtable (resulting in a change on the UI). I come from a scripting background, applescript, VBscript, powershell. I've not experience with C, but that'll be the next thing I will learn for sure ! Could you recommend any places to learn C? C+ Is what I'm leaning towards. Josh

Comment: You should add this answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I pared down your script a bit for a working proof of concept - add back in anything you needed:

```
@('System.Drawing','System.Windows.Forms') | %{ [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($_) | Out-Null }
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles() | out-null
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{
    MaximizeBox = $False
    KeyPreview = $True
    FormBorderStyle = 1
    Name = "form1"
    StartPosition = 1
    backcolor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,240,240,240)
    ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size -Property @{Height = 600;Width = 1200}
}
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 

$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer -Property @{Interval = 1000} #Forms.Timer doesn't support AutoReset property
$script:num=0 #scope must be at script level to increment in event handler 
$timer.start()
$timer.add_Tick({
    $script:num +=1
    write-host "test $script:num"
    $vollabel.text=$script:num
})

$vollabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label -Property @{Location = "0,0"}
$form1.Controls.Add($vollabel)
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
$timer.stop() #This will keep running in the background unless you stop it
```

A few notes:

- Form.ShowDialog() is blocking and stops the script execution.
- System.**Windows.Forms**.Timer has slightly different properties than System.Timers.Timer and can take a ScriptBlock or a function name as a parameter to add_Tick()
- An event handler ScriptBlock has its own scope, but you can share variables with the $ScopeName:VariableName syntax. I couldn't get $num to increment unless I set the scope to $Script